# rails3 : URL rewriting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, url

I have a rails 3 application in which my users can belong to group. What I want to do is to transform the group's URLs.

The group's URLs are like that :

```
http://www.my_website/groups/group_id
```

What I want is to transform my URLs like that :

```
http://www.group_name.my_website
```

Exemple for the the 'driver' group :

```
http://www.my_website/groups/9  ==> http://www.driver.my_website
```

Is it possible with rails ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RailsCast for you](http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3)

Hope, It will solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use **request.subdomain** instead of **id**.
[RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3)